# Deserializar coleccion JSON en C#

Tags: c#, json

**Contexto**:
Estoy trabajando con una API que provee datos sobre cuerpos celestes. Al llamar al endpoint que lista todos los cuerpos celestes, recibo una colección de objetos JSON que representan cada uno de los cuerpos. La estructura de la colección es la siguiente:

```
{ 
  bodies: [
            {...},
            {...}
          ]
}
```

**Objetivo**
Deserializar la clave *bodies* con el fin de almacenar cada JSON que contiene, en una instancia creada en C#

**Código clave**
Tengo 3 clases actualmente:
**Body_loader** que se encarga de realizar las peticiones a la API
**Body** que representa un cuerpo celeste
**BodyCollection** que representa una coleccion de cuerpos celestes (en la API, la colección de objetos JSON)

```
//Body_Loader.cs

// Método que permite obtener la colección JSON
   public async Task<BodyCollection> getBodyList() {

     var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync(url);

     var bodyCollection  = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<BodyCollection>(await streamTask);

     return bodyCollection;
   }
```

```
// Body

namespace astroSharp
{
  class Body {

    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id{get; set;}
  
    [JsonPropertyName("englishName")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("isPlanet")]
    public bool isPlanet{get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("inclination")]
    public float Inclination {get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("mass.massValue")]
    public float Mass {get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("density")]
    public float Density {get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("gravity")]
    public float Gravity{get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("aphelion")]
    public int Aphelion{get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("perihelion")]
    public int Perihelion{get; set;}

    [JsonPropertyName("sideralRotation")]
    public float SideralRotation{get; set;}

  }
}
```

```
// BodyCollection.cs

namespace astroSharp
{
  class BodyCollection {

    [JsonPropertyName("bodies")]
    public List<Body> Bodies{get; set;}
  
  }
}
```

**Problema detectado**
Dado el código anterior, no sé como deserializar para conseguir que cada objeto JSON de la colección recibida, sea una instancia de tipo Body dentro de la lista de BodyCollection para así, luego en el método principal, pueda recorrer tal lista y pintar los datos que necesito de cada cuerpo celeste.

Gracias

Comment: Te puedo recomendar, basado en que tu pregunta es muy abierta y no muestras todos los datos, que utilices la herramienta [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) dado que necesitaras un root

Comment: De acuerdo. Gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que json2csharp crea un modelo de clases a partir de un JSON recibido, permitiendo agilizar en el proceso de deserializar un objeto JSON no?. Estoy aprendiendo C# y desconozco muchas herramientas todavía.

Comment: A si es, le pegas la estructura y te va a devolver la clase para que la utilices

Answer (score 1):

Viendo tu codigo el problema que creo que tenes, porque no estas publicando el problema que te muestra visual studio, es que estas leyendo un stream cuando lo que te llega es un string.
Luego te falto leer el contenido de la respuesta, ya que segun veo estas queriendo deserealizar toda la respuesta, encabezado, body, etc.
Ya con esto, donde llames tu metodo tendras tu listado de objetos de cuerpos celeste.

Como no se que libreria usas para deserealizar, yo use Newtownsoft.Json.

```
public async Task<BodyCollection> getBodyList() 
{
 var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

 if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
    var bodyCollection  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BodyCollection>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
 
    return bodyCollection;
 }
}
```